# Repeatedly check 2 different numbers to be equal to another number in python

Tags: python, for-loop, math, while-loop, iteration

If you import a number (g) greater or equal to 0 then you should be able to write it as: g = (2^m)*r , (m > 0 and r has to be odd).
I tried different things and searching on the web but could find an answer.
It's a question related to while/for loops because it's connected to that chapter in my studies.

This is one of the things I tried so far:

```
g = int(input(' '))
m = 0
r = 1
while m >= 0:
        m += 1 
        if g == (2**m)*r:
                break
        else:
                r+=2
print(m)
print(r)
```

But I always come on infinite loops...

If anyone can help me, i'd be thankful

Comment: Because you are increasing at the same time `g` and `r`.

Comment: Sounds like a math problem. Suppose `r` was even, then you could write `r=2r'` and thus `g = (2**(m+1))r'`. This equation, in fact, covers all the integers `>1`.

Comment: Thus, approach it so: take `g`, as long as it's even, do `g' = d/2; m+=1`. Now you're left with odd `g'''' == r` and you're done.

Comment: I think it belongs to math.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure every number could be reperesented as `(2**m) *r` given that m and r are integers, since 15 is composed of `3,5` and none of those factors is a power of 2. [Edit I did assume that 2 is a power of 1+,  but if it could be power of zero then that would  be correct]

But following on and assuming your input are numbers that are surely can be represented as `(2**m) *r`, you need to fix a few things in your loop to make it work, the solution you are trying to follow is a striaght brute force one but not complete, you need to try every value of m with every value of r, that does not happen in your loop so you may miss the solution and go into infinite loop in most cases.

A more polished solution would be to first factor the input number to get how many 2s it actually has

```
import math
g = 5
m = 0
r = 1
while True:
    if(g % r == 0 and math.log2(g/r).is_integer()):
        m = math.log2(g/r)
        break
    r += 2

print(m)
print(r)
```

an example here let's take 12
divide 12 by 2 you get 6
it's still divides two so we continue, 6/2 gives 3
3 does not divide 2 so we end the loop and we have r = 3 and m = 2
`12 = 2**2  * 3`
which is correct.

and here is your solution fixed

```
g = 3
m = 0
r = 1
while g != (2**m) * r:
    if g < (2**m) * r:
        m = -1
        r += 2
    m += 1

print(m)
print(r)
```

Comment: `15 == (2**0) * 15`.

Comment: Nice catch, I fixed the brute force approach, but I think now we have more than one solution in most cases, if there is no criteria then any solution found would work I guess